# How to deserialize with jackson objectmapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to convert a json (shown below) into a java object. I have created java classes for the json objects without using any jackson annotations for now.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestJunkie {

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\r\n" + 
                "   \"Info\":{\r\n" + 
                "       \"prop1\": \"value1\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"prop2\": \"value2\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"prop3\": \"value3\"\r\n" + 
                "   },\r\n" + 
                "   \"Data\":{\r\n" + 
                "       \"prop1\": \"value1\",\r\n" + 
                "       \"prop2\": \"value2\"\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "}";

        Pack pack = objectMapper.readValue(json, Pack.class);
        System.out.println(pack);
    }

}
```

I converted the above Json object into a Java class called "Pack" below:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

public class Pack {

    private Info info;
    private Data data;

    public Info getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("info", info).append("data", data).toString();
    }

}
```

I have deliberately omitted the classes for Info and Data. Their variables, getters, setters match the json. I can include them if you want.

I get the following exception. Why does this exception occur & how do I fix it ?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Info" (class com.tester.Jacksons.Pack), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "data", "info"])
 at [Source: (String)"{
    "Info":{
        "prop1": "value1",
        "prop2": "value2",
        "prop3": "value3"
    },
    "Data":{
        "prop1": "value1",
        "prop2": "value2"
    }
}"; line: 2, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.tester.Jacksons.Pack["Info"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:60)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:822)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1582)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1560)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2992)
    at com.tester.Jacksons.TestJunkie.main(TestJunkie.java:22)
```

Comment: share Info and Data class as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties inside Pack are not matching the names because in json it's starting with capital case letter. 
Hence, update `Pack` as follows:

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

```
public class Pack {

    @JsonProperty("Info")
    private Info info;
    @JsonProperty("Data")
    private Data data;

    public Info getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("info", info).append("data", data).toString();
    }

}
```

Also, in case there are properties which are not specified in Info or  Data class. Use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation on class to Ignore unknown properties.

**Updates**

Using annotations could not be very handy if you have to use same Classes say as Hibernate Entities or in other places. Hence, My recommendation is that you perform `serialization and deserialization using Dtos` and then later put values from these Dtos to your other objects wherever you need to. You could use good apis like `mapstruct` to do such creation of  objects.

Comment: Thanks ! your solution is correct. I will use json annotation after all. I wanted to avoid this because it may be used by spring developers who never use jackson annotations. They just put underscores in their getters & setters instead. Btw, i got the same error when I changed my json objects to lowercase.

Comment: Hey! I think then you need to revisit your code architecturally. Make Dto classes to serialize and deserialize from and to json . Let me edit my answer to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Your object's keys are lower case and in the json they are upper-camel-case.
If this naming scheme is consistent you can just set the naming stategy on the object mapper.

```
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy);
```

Comment: @rbqa `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;` But I believe this approach will fail as soon as you again break this naming convention. Hence, use JsonProperty annotation on property.

Comment: Though ! That's right @magnus and i think it's good to know feature of jackson

Comment: The naming strategy is not working anyway. I want to avoid using json properties for now.

Comment: @rbqa that's like you have a solution but you don't want to follow that :). So either fix names in json or specify which field maps to which property in json.